# Lambda can't find the file when code version inserted into Handler property in CloudFormation template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

The artefact that I create and deploy has a version number in it. It is of the form:

```
universe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

where the `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is the version.

Now the CloudFormation template has the Handler mapped through a Fn::Join function:

```
  UFunctionCelestial:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtefactRepositoryBucket
        S3Key: !Join [ '', [!Sub '${AWS::StackName}-', !Ref CodeVersion, '.zip' ] ]
      Handler: !Join [ '', [!Sub '${AWS::StackName}-', !Ref CodeVersion, '/src/lambdas/celestial_persist_function.handler'] ]
      Role: !GetAtt [ UIAMRoleFunctionServiceRoleCelestial, Arn ]
      Runtime: python3.7
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CELESTIAL_TABLE_NAME: !Ref UTableCelestial
          PRIMARY_KEY: id
    DependsOn:
      - UIAMRoleFunctionServiceRolePolicyCelestial
      - UIAMRoleFunctionServiceRoleCelestial

...SNIP...

Parameters:
  ArtefactRepositoryBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket for asset "foundry-cdk/CelestialHandler/Code"
  CodeVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for asset version "foundry-cdk/CelestialHandler/Code"
```

I guess most of this is irrelevant, except the `Handler` property

Now the `!Ref CodeVersion` code version for that line seems to evaluate as `0/0/1-SNAPSHOT` for some reason, even though I call this template with the command:

```sh
aws2 cloudformation deploy \
    --template-file ${CF_TEMPLATE_FILE} \
    --region ${ACCOUNT_REGION} \
    --stack-name ${PROJECT_NAME} \
    --force-upload \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
    --parameter-overrides \
        ArtefactRepositoryBucket=${S3_AWS_RELEASES_BUCKET} \
        CodeVersion=${APPLICATION_VERSION}
```

I echoed out the `${APPLICATION_VERSION}` and, yep, it evaluates to `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

and yet when I go to the console and look at my Lambda I get the message:

> Lambda can't find the file universe-0/0/1-SNAPSHOT/src/lambdas/celestial_persist_function.py. Make sure that your handler upholds the format: file-name.method.

So my question is, why is CloudFormation turning my dots into slashes and giving the Lambda a bum reference?

Comment: did you try double-quote your "${application_version}"?

Comment: actually, that's what I started with. I noticed that I had `${APPLICATION_VERSION}` double quoted and ${S3_AWS_RELEASES_BUCKET} not double quoted, when I saw this error, I removed the double quotes as one of my early tries at fixing this. The quoting (or not quoting) ended up making no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not cloudformation what doing it. The behavior you are seeing is normal behavior.

Generally, When you define the handler as "folder1.folder2.file.handler", it will look for a `folder1`, then look for `folder2` inside that, then look for the file `file.py` inside. Finally, the `file.py` is expected to have a function named `handler`.

I am assuming that your zip file has a top folder called `src`. In that case, your handler should be defined as `src.lambdas.celestial_persist_function.handler` since you have already mentioned where your zip file is using the `S3Key`.

hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm this now, I changed the versioning in setup.py to `0-0-1-SNAPSHOT` and all was suddenly well. Thanks for your answer.